# Remove Dot at end of line of the string in SQLserver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would to like to remove the dot at end of the line alone if exists in the string in SQL server.

**Example:**

```
ABC Private's co., ltd.
```

**Required output:**

```
ABC Private's co., ltd
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `like` to check for a `.` at the end of the string.

```
declare @S nvarchar(max) = 'ABC Private''s co., ltd.';

select case when @S like '%.' 
         then left(@S, len(@S) - 1) 
         else @S 
       end;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @a varchar(100);

SET @a = '''ABC Private''s co., ltd.';

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    WHERE SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@a), 1, 1) = '.'
)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, 1, ( DATALENGTH(@a)-1 ))
END;
```

Comment: Why are you using DATALENGTH function instead of LEN function ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT LEFT(C, LEN(C) - PATINDEX('.', RIGHT(C, 1)))
```

should do the trick. 
C of course is the column to remove last dot from.

PATINDEX looks for string and returns 1, if it is found, or 0 if it isn't.

So we feed it the rightmost character of the column C. It is either '.' (-> 1) or it isn't (-> 0) , then we subtract the result and return either the whole column LEFT(C,LEN(C) - 0) or all of it minus the last character LEFT(C,LEN(C) - 1)

This avoids all kinds of nested statements and if/thens and uses simple T-SQL string functions.

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli added some explanations

Answer (score 0):

I've listed two ways you could do it. These should be compatible through many versions of SQL.

```
   --option 1, don't actually change the data
   DECLARE @this varchar(255);

   SET @this = 'ABC Private''s co., ltd.';

   SELECT   @this = CASE
                    WHEN Right(@this, 1) = '.' THEN Left(@this, ( Len( @this ) - 1 ))
                    ELSE @this
                END;

   SELECT   @this;

   --option 2, change the data

   CREATE TABLE #this
   (
       yourColumn varchar(255)
   );

   INSERT INTO #this( yourColumn )VALUES( N'ABC Private''s co., ltd.' );

   UPDATE   #this
   SET      yourColumn = CASE
                        WHEN Right(yourColumn, 1) = '.' THEN Left(yourColumn, ( 
   Len( yourColumn ) - 1 ))
                        ELSE @this
                    END;

   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #this AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when right(COL,1)='.' then left(COL,len(COL)-1) else COL end
```

Answer (score -1):

I know its an old question but looks like all the answers are complicated.

So this one might be so simple.

For SQL Server

```
select case

when right(rtrim(f1),1) = '.' then substring(rtrim(f1),1,len(rtrim(f1))-1)

else f1 END AS f1

From Table1
```

For PGSQL and MYSQL

```
select rtrim(Enames,'.') from table_name
```

Hope it helps someone..

Comment: Msg 174 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
The rtrim function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: @TomV-TeamMonica Enames is string/column name. I tried with PGSQL it works

Comment: But the question is tagged with SQL Server and T-SQL and the title mentions "SQL Server" so that's where I tested it.